# What is the etymology of "Arrivano i nostri!"

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

A che cosa si riferisce la parola "nostri" nell'espressione idiomatica "arrivano i nostri!" che, se capisco bene, significa che si è oramai arrivati alla conclusione? Qual è l'etimologia di questo costrutto?

Comment: Non significa genericamente che si è arrivati alla conclusione, ma appunto che un intervento inatteso dell'ultima ora risolve la situazione: è quasi una sorta di *deus ex machina*.

Comment: Ho trovato un "arrivano i nostri" in un [libro](https://books.google.it/books?id=3PpDAQAAMAAJ&q=%22arrivano+i+nostri%22&dq=%22arrivano+i+nostri%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAjgUahUKEwjj5rnnrJLHAhVXKogKHekGADY) ("Alla guerra sui mari" di Arnaldo Fraccaroli, ed. Fratelli Treves) del __1917__, quindi non si può pensare che l'espressione sia nata con la traduzione dei film western.

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da [wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossario_delle_frasi_fatte): "Si dice solitamente quando arriva qualcuno in soccorso di chi è in difficoltà. La frase ha origine dai classici film western, nei quali il provvidenziale arrivo della cavalleria salvava i protagonisti da morte certa."

From [wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossario_delle_frasi_fatte): "It is usually said when someone comes to the rescue of those in need. The phrase originates from the classic Western movies, where the providential arrival of the cavalry saved the protagonists from a certain death. "

Comment: Già altrove è stato ricordato che la Wikipedia, e in particolare quella italiana, non è una fonte in sé. Se, come dovrebbe, riporta le fonti delle sue affermazioni, sono loro a fare testo; se, come in questo caso, l'affermazione è priva di fonti, vale come qualsiasi altra cosa trovata in rete, e cioè quanto l'opinione a naso di ognuno di noi.

Comment: @DaG Ok, cerco una fonte più attendibile.

Answer (score 5):

Non penso abbia un'etimologia particolare, penso derivi semplicemente dal fatto che il soggetto viene troncato, diventando implicito, e l'espressione quindi diventa applicabile a molti casi (e in ultimo idiomatica). E.g.:

> Arrivano i nostri [alleati]!
>
> Arrivano i nostri [amici]!
>
> Arrivano i nostri [compagni]!

Answer (score 3):

Suggerisco di sentire "Arrivano i nostri" di Natalino Otto (1951) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lAN-_1cvME che conferma la risposta di Marco, che ovviamente sottoscrivo (sono del 1943 ...)
Essenso stato invitato a completare la risposta, aggiungo gli elementi western della canzone: squiulli di trombe, un bandito, i nostri, un generale, i monti del Far West, spari, lo sceriffo ...
Quella è l'origine.

Comment: Avevo “flaggato” questa come una non-risposta (è più un commento a quella di @MarcoCantarini), ma in realtà, un po' arricchita, potrebbe forse dare la vera risposta sull'origine del modo di dire.

Comment: Penso che servirebbe una fonte di una certa autorevolezza più che altro; sarebbe sbagliato inferire che quella sia l'origine per il solo fatto che sia stata citata allora, perché non esclude il fatto che sia stato fatto già prima; comunque anch'io avevo pensato a questo inizialmente, perché senza alcun dubbio l'espressione è stata abusata nei film western citati da Marco Cantarini, comunque il [commento di Walter Tross](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5738/what-is-the-etymology-of-arrivano-i-nostri#comment10082_5738) sembrerebbe contraddire quest'ipotesi.